# Golang package not found

Tags: go

I am new to go lang and I m trying out my first app. I hit a roadblock while importing a package from another go file.

I have two go files. 1. hello.go with main package. 2. data.go with data package.

The code inside hello.go is

```
   package main

   import (
    "datatypes/data"
    "fmt"
       )

  func main() {
      fmt.Print("Hello world!!\n")
      /* calling the first function from another function */
      myFirstFunction()
   }

  func myFirstFunction() {
      fmt.Print("This is the first function\n")
      data.WorkingWithDataTypes()
  }
```

data.go code is

```
   package data

  import "fmt"

  /*WorkingWithDataTypes is a function to work with go lang data types */
  func WorkingWithDataTypes() {
    x := 10
    fmt.Print(x)
   }
```

When I run the main function by running go run hello.go I am getting the below error

```
**hello.go:10:2: cannot find package "firstapp/data" in any of:     
/usr/local/go/src/firstapp/data (from $GOROOT)  
/Users/home/workspaces/Go/Project1/src/firstapp/data (from $GOPATH)**
```

I set my go path as /Users/home/workspaces/Go/Project1. I am not sure where I make the mistake. any help?

I set the GO PATH as

[image]

As per the go doc [for go path](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)

I created the project structure as below and put my code below src folder.

src/datatypes has the package data. 
src/main has the package main.

But still go run hello.go is failing as it is not able to find the package datatypes/data

[image]

Comment: Packages need to be a directory. See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). Start off with a single `GOPATH`, you can even use the default of `$HOME/go` and not worry about it at all.

Comment: You should place your project `firstapp` under `/usr/local/go/src` for it is where your `GOPATH` points to. Moreover you can't have 2 different packages in the same directory. So `data.go` should be in package `main`too.

Comment: @TheophileDano: no, that is `GOROOT`, and you should _never_ put your code in `GOROOT`.

Comment: @JimB before he edited the post I thought I had seen gopath set to this location...

Comment: @TheophileDano: `/usr/local/go/` is the default Go install path -- it should never be GOPATH. (P.S., can view the edit history of the post)

Comment: @volker I edited my question. It is unique as I believe i follow the documents but the code is still breaking.

Comment: @jimB and @ TheophileDano i modified the structure and set the GOPATH to point to my project1 directory but still unable to find the package.

Comment: As I said in the first comment, a package must be a directory. You don't have an import path of  `datatypes/data` because there is no `data` directory.

Comment: @JimB thanks I changed my package declaration as datatypes instead of datatypes/data in the hello.go and it fixed it. Thanks for the help.